# Why Is Unmarshal Failing With A Nested Struct?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am trying to retrieve information using Reddit's API. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) is some documentation on their json response, however, I got most of my information by just viewing the link in the browser and pretty-printing the response [here](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print).

The following code behaves as intended when the "Replies" field is commented out, but fails when it's not.

[edit] getData() is a function I wrote that uses Go's http Client to get a site response in bytes.

```
type redditThing struct {
    Data struct {
        Children []struct {
            Data struct {
                Permalink string
                Subreddit string
                Title     string
                Body      string
                Replies   redditThing
            }
        }
    }
}

func visitLink(link string) {
    println("visiting:", link)

    var comments []redditThing
    if err := json.Unmarshal(getData(link+".json?raw_json=1"), &comments); err != nil {
        logError.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

This throws the following error

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field .Data.Children.Data.Replies.Data.Children.Data.Replies.Data.Children.Data.Replies of type main.redditThing
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

[edit] [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cybersecurity/comments/g0mp8v/all_free_curated_list_with_6_virtual_cons_34.json?raw_json=1) a link to some data causing the program to fail

Comment: Edit the question to show an example of JSON that you are trying to parse.  The page https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print is blank for me.

Comment: @MuffinTop I added a link to some JSON data, since putting the JSON data here would result in a huge wall of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replies` field can be the empty string or a `redditThing`.  Fix by adding an [Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) function to handle the empty string:

```
func (rt *redditThing) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Do nothing if data is the empty string.
    if bytes.Equal(data, []byte(`""`)) {
        return nil
    }

    // Prevent recursion by declaring type x with 
    // same underlying type as redditThing, but
    // with no methods.
    type x redditThing

    return json.Unmarshal(data, (*x)(rt))
}
```

The `x` type is used to prevent indefinite recursion.  If the final line of the method is `json.Unmarshal(data, rt)`, then `json.Unmarshal` function will call `redditThing.UnmarshalJSON` method which calls `json.Unmarshal` function and so on. Boom!

The statement `type x redditThing` declares a new type named `x` with the same underlying type as `redditThing`.  The underlying type is a anonymous struct type.  The underlying type has no methods, and crucially, the underlying type does not have the `UnmarshalJSON` method. This prevents recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 2 questions
1) what exactly is happening from "type x redditThing" and after?
2) how would this change if I'm unmarshalling into an array of redditThings?

Comment: Thank you! implementing this method before calling json.Unmarshal() on the slice of structs did the trick!